# Getting info through 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm following the SQL tutorial from w3schools.

I want to get the value of all orders delivered by a shipper. I don't have any idea about how I can get these details as the info are in different tables and the INNER JOIN didn't worked for me.

Database: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_groupby
By now, I managed to get the number of orders by each shipper.

```
SELECT Shippers.ShipperName,COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Shippers
ON Orders.ShipperID=Shippers.ShipperID
GROUP BY ShipperName;
```

How could I get the value of those?

Comment: What do you mean by the "value" of the orders?  What you have is a record for each shipper including the total count of orders for each shipper.  What results are you looking for?

Comment: Can you please share the tables' structures, some sample data and the result you'd like to get for this sample?

Comment: "How could I get the value of those?" What is a value... and the value of what? Can you explain exactly what you mean here?

Comment: I mean, every order have a price. There is a OrderDetails table with a `productID`. The price of the product is on the `Product` table. @Mureinik, all I have is in the w3scools link...

Comment: So "Value" is "Sum of Price". That makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To bring the `Price` of a `Product` into your query you will need to join in tables `OrderDetails` to the `Order` table on the `Orders.Id` and then join in the `Products` table to the `OrderDetail` table on `ProductID`

```
SELECT Shippers.ShipperName,
    COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders,
    Sum(Products.price * OrderDetails.Quantity) AS SumOfPrice
FROM Orders
    LEFT JOIN Shippers ON Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID
    LEFT JOIN OrderDetails ON ORders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
    LEFT JOIN Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID
GROUP BY ShipperName;
```

I just stuck with `LEFT JOIN` here as your example used, but an `INNER JOIN` would work just as well and be more efficient.

The FROM clause of the SQL statement is one of the first parts of the SQL to run against your database. It establishes which tables we are grabbing information from and the relationship between those tables (using the `ON` keyword). So here we bring in 4 tables, and use the `ON` keyword to show the relationship between all of them using their respective IDs. Then we can add their fields to the `SELECT` portion of the SQL statement and aggregate where needed.

Comment: Right idea, but you need to multiply the price by the quantity.

Comment: Thanks @DanBracuk. I've updated the query to do extended price. That makes more sense.

Comment: I think I start to understand how should work. I tried to run this select but I get an error `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID LEFT JOIN OrderDetails ON ORders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID LEFT JOIN Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID'.`  Any idea to fix it?

Comment: I just copied and pasted the query I've written into the link you have in your post and it runs fine. Are you certain you've copied it completely?

Comment: So strange. Works in Chrome but not in Firefox. Again, thank you for your help. I'm gonna play with a few more JOINS today.

Comment: That is completely unexpected. I'm glad you figured that one out. I would have pulled my hair out before I thought of switching browsers to make a SQL statement work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the "sum" of the product prices, that would be very similar to what you already have.  Note how you currently use the `COUNT()` function to get the count, you can use the `SUM()` function to get the total of any numeric column.

Something like this:

```
SELECT
  Shippers.ShipperName,
  COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders,
  SUM(Products.Price) AS PriceOfOrders
FROM
  Orders
  INNER JOIN Shippers ON Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID
  INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
  INNER JOIN Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID
GROUP BY
  ShipperName
```

Or perhaps the price also needs to be multiplied by the quantity in this calculation?  Something like this:

```
SELECT
  Shippers.ShipperName,
  COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders,
  SUM(Products.Price * OrderDetails.Quantity) AS PriceOfOrders
FROM
  Orders
  INNER JOIN Shippers ON Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID
  INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
  INNER JOIN Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID
GROUP BY
  ShipperName
```

It's up to your understanding of the table structure and the data, really.  But the concept is the same, grouping by a value and applying a calculation to the grouped values (count or sum).

Comment: This is a repeat of JNevill's answer which was posted 3 minutes earlier.

Comment: @DanBracuk: It's possible for two people to reach the same conclusion simultaneously.  What's your point?